# Issue with ubuntu writing a MBR on an SSD

Tags: partitioning, mbr, boot-partition

So far I have two disks, one SSD for my main os(FreeBSD) that is connected with the NVME bus and one SATA3 HDD for ubuntu.

I installed ubuntu much later than FreeBSD for a project that required some libraries that are not available on FreeBSD on the HDD, but for some reason it created an entry on the SSD.

The point is, ubuntu is not on the SSD, yet it created the entry(I am guessing it is the Master Boot Record because the disk size did not change, it is a 500kb partition).

Is there a way to delete this partition from the SSD and completely isolate ubuntu on its own disk?

I don't mind changing the booting disk when I need to, I just want them to be completely separated.

Thank you for your time in advance!

Comment: You mention MBR; which is the first 512 bytes of a disk, and exists outside of partitioning (reserved since the 1980s for the MBR) thus won't relate to any 500KB partition (no need; the sector is reserved on every drive & allocating a partition for a single sector wastes more space than is saved on anything larger than a 2.88MB floppy disk).  An EFI partition makes more sense, but I'm only guessing as you provided no specifics, no release details etc.

Comment: Are you booting in UEFI mode or in BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode)? Please check with the command line `test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo bios` and edit the original question to tell us.